# How to make fields editable temporarily in salesforce

Tags: community, salesforce1-app

I have a "Sales user" profile with read-only access to all account fields and I have a button that opens up a visual flow with account address input fields. 
basically what I want to do is, I want to make address fields temporarily editable.
**user click button,visual flow with input fields opens up,user inputs the values, press save and in this moment permissions should be "extended" to allow data save.**

How this could be done? I could not find a solution for this online. Or perhaps I am not searching properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way would be to assign the sales users only account page layouts where all fields are made read only while the user still has edit access on the fields in his profile/permission set.

Doing this however will still allow users to edit account fields through API or list views as they still have edit permissions available.